# Container for list of ranges

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, container, interval

I made a C++ container of an ordered list of integers, that, in order to save space, I save as ranges:

For example, the list \$ \{1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,20\} \$ is saved in memory as \$ \{(1,3), (5,9), (20,20)\} \$.

I have doubts of the iterator used to show all the numbers that are include on one list is right. Mainly because my iterator doesn't allow to modify elements on the container.

And in general, I wrote it in C++11.

```
template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
class RangeListIterator; // undefined

template<typename T>
class RangeListIterator<T>{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using RangeItem = std::pair< value_type, value_type >;
    using RangeItemList = std::list<RangeItem>;
    using RangeItem_iterator = typename RangeItemList::iterator;

    RangeListIterator( RangeItem_iterator it, value_type val,
                       RangeItem_iterator itEnd );

    bool operator!=( const RangeListIterator<T> & b ) const;

    RangeListIterator& operator++();
    RangeListIterator operator++( int );

    const value_type& operator*() const;

private:
    RangeItem_iterator m_listIt;
    RangeItem_iterator m_listEnd;
    value_type m_val;
};

template<typename T>
RangeListIterator<T>::RangeListIterator( RangeItem_iterator it,
                                         value_type val,
                                         RangeItem_iterator itEnd)
    : m_listIt{ it }, m_listEnd{ itEnd }, m_val{ val }
{
    // empty
}

template<typename T>
bool RangeListIterator<T>::operator!=( const RangeListIterator<T> & b ) const{
    return (m_listIt != b.m_listIt) or (m_val != b.m_val);
}

template<typename T>
RangeListIterator<T>& RangeListIterator<T>::operator++() {
    if( m_val == std::numeric_limits<T>::max() ){
        ++m_listIt;
        m_val = 0;
    }else{
        ++m_val;
        if( m_val > m_listIt->second ){
            ++m_listIt;
            if( m_listIt == m_listEnd ){
                m_val = 0;
            }else{
                m_val = m_listIt->first;
            }
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
RangeListIterator<T> RangeListIterator<T>::operator++( int ) {
    auto temp = *this;
    ++*this;
    return temp;
}

template<typename T>
const typename RangeListIterator<T>::value_type&
RangeListIterator<T>::operator*() const{
    return m_val;
}

template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
class RangeList; // undefined

template<typename T>
class RangeList<T>{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using RangeItem = std::pair< value_type, value_type >;
    using RangeItemList = std::list<RangeItem>;
    using RangeItem_iterator = typename RangeItemList::iterator;
    using RangeItem_const_iterator = typename RangeItemList::const_iterator;
    using iterator = RangeListIterator<T>;

    void insert( const value_type val );
    void remove( const value_type val );
    bool contains( const value_type val ) const;

    RangeItem_iterator beginItem();
    RangeItem_const_iterator beginItem() const;

    RangeItem_iterator endItem();
    RangeItem_const_iterator endItem() const;

    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

private:
    std::list<RangeItem> m_items;
};

template<typename T>
void RangeList<T>::insert( const T val ){
    for( auto it = std::begin(m_items) ; it != std::end(m_items) ; ++it ){
        if( val < it->first ){
            if( val == (it->first - 1) ){
                it->first = val;
            }else{
                m_items.emplace( it, std::make_pair( val, val ) );
            }
            return;
        }else if( val <= it->second ){
            return;
        }else if( val == (it->second + 1) ){
        auto next = std::next(it);
            if( next != std::end(m_items) ){
                if( (val >= next->first - 1) and (val <= next->second) ){
                    it->second = next->second;
                    m_items.erase( next );
                    return;
                }
            }
            it->second = val;
            return;
        }
    }

    m_items.emplace_back( std::make_pair( val, val ) );
}

template<typename T>
void RangeList<T>::remove( const T val ){
    for( auto it = std::begin(m_items) ; it != std::end(m_items) ; ++it ){
        if( val >= it->first and val <= it->second ){
            if( it->first == it->second ){
                m_items.erase( it );
                return;
            }
            if( val == it->first ){
                it->first = it->first + 1;
                return;
            }
            if( val == it->second ){
                it->second = it->second - 1;
                return;
            }
            m_items.emplace( it, std::make_pair( it->first, val - 1 ) );
            it->first = val + 1;
            return;
        }
        if( val < it->first ){
            return;
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
bool RangeList<T>::contains( const T val ) const{
    for( const auto & it: m_items ){
        auto rmin = it.first <= val;
        if( rmin and (it.second >= val) ){
            return true;
        }
        if( not rmin ){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

template<typename T>
inline
typename RangeList<T>::RangeItem_iterator
RangeList<T>::beginItem(){
    return m_items.begin();
}

template<typename T>
inline
typename RangeList<T>::RangeItem_const_iterator
RangeList<T>::beginItem() const{
    return m_items.begin();
}

template<typename T>
inline
typename RangeList<T>::RangeItem_iterator
RangeList<T>::endItem(){
    return m_items.end();
}

template<typename T>
inline
typename RangeList<T>::RangeItem_const_iterator
RangeList<T>::endItem() const{
    return m_items.end();
}

template<typename T>
typename RangeList<T>::iterator
RangeList<T>::begin(){
    auto listIt = std::begin(m_items);
    return RangeListIterator<T>( listIt, listIt->first, std::end(m_items) );
}

template<typename T>
inline
typename RangeList<T>::iterator
RangeList<T>::end(){
    return RangeListIterator<T>( std::end(m_items), 0, std::end(m_items) );
}
```

An example of use:

```
RangeList<int> range;

range.insert( 1 );
range.insert( 2 );
range.insert( 4 );
range.insert( 7 );
range.insert( 8 );
range.insert( 6 );

for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i ){
    cout << " test " << i << " = " << range.contains(i) << endl;
}

for( auto it = range.beginItem() ; it != range.endItem() ; ++it ){
    cout << " range (" << it->first << " , " << it->second << ")" << endl;
}

for( auto v: range ){
    cout << " val " << v << endl;
}

RangeList<unsigned int> rangeu;

rangeu.insert( 4 );
rangeu.insert( 7 );
rangeu.insert( 1 );
rangeu.insert( 2 );
rangeu.insert( 0 );
rangeu.insert( -1 );
rangeu.insert( -2 );
rangeu.insert( 6 );

for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i ){
    cout << " test " << i << " " << rangeu.contains(i) << endl;
}

for( auto it = rangeu.beginItem() ; it != rangeu.endItem() ; ++it ){
    cout << " range (" << it->first << " , " << it->second << ")" << endl;
}

for( auto v: rangeu ){
    cout << " val " << v << endl;
}

return 0;
```

**UPDATED**:

1. Fixed insert. Now it merges two continuous ranges when you insert the element between them. E.g:  \$ \{(1,3),(5,9)\} + insert(4) \$ generates \$ \{(1,9)\} \$.
2. Added `remove` method.

Comment: If the iterator is not there to change the contents of the container then just make it a const iterator.

Comment: You don't need the `inline` keywords, especially in a header file.

Comment: Also, I can think a way without saving the `end` on the iterator.

Comment: @Jamal I don't think so. Maybe you are thinking on definitions inside class declaration.

Comment: I think it may be easier to represent the list with ranges that don't include the length. ie. `{[1,4),[5,10),[20,21)}` I hope my math notation is correct.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I don't see the benefit of use [n,m+1) ranges instead of [n,m] ones.

Comment: I can see several efficient ways of solving the problem. What do you intend to do with the data structure, other than save space? In other words, what operations need to be fast?

Comment: @mrm the most important operation is check when an element is inside the range.

Comment: @Zhen Is there an upper bound for how large your integers to be stored are? For example, if you are storing ints, can the largest value you store be MAX_INT?

Comment: @Zhen: Its not a big deal. Technically there will be very little difference (I can see a minor optimization when inserting new items to detect range expansions and another for range merges). But they are both minor. The main reason is to stay with a standard idiom used by C++ (in that `begin`->`end` is a range where `end` is one past the end of the range). A user not familiar with your code may expect you to be using standard C++ conventions and thus introduce bugs while doing maintenance.

Comment: I get your point @LokiAstari, but I see that you can insert(MAX_T) with open ranges [n,MAXT_T+1), you will need to check this case always or have an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fairly minor point, but I'm not a huge fan of using `enable_if` here. For example, if we declare a `RangeList<double>`, we'll get the following as errors:

> range_iter.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> range_iter.cpp:53:21: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if'
>        RangeList double_range;
>
> range_iter.cpp:53:21: error: template argument 2 is invalid
>
> range_iter.cpp:53:35: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
>        RangeList double_range;

This also requires adding "clutter" like:

```
template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
class RangeListIterator; // undefined

template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
class RangeList; // undefined
```

Instead, I'd rather just use a `static_assert` at the top of each class:

```
static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "T must be an integral type!");
```

This has the benefit of cutting down on the above clutter, as well as giving nicer compiler error messages:

> range_iter.hpp: In instantiation of 'class RangeList':
>
> range_iter.cpp:53:23:   required from here
>
> range_iter.hpp:92:5: error: static assertion failed: T must be an integral type!
>        static_assert(std::is_integral::value, "T must be an integral type!");

Comment: Great, I like it,

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your setting, a bitvector might be a *much* better idea (or *much* worse!). This depends on how sparse your ranges actually are. The following might give you some ideas, and perhaps you might want to incorporate it into your data structure, and use some method to change the internal representation if needed.

```
const static std::size_t S = 128; 
std::bitset<S> range; // We can now store 128 values using only 128 bits

// Is 5 present?
bool five = range.test(4);
```

... and so on. You can support many operations in constant time. If you know how large S can be beforehand, great. If not, use a dynamic variant, such as boost::dynamic_bitset.

Comment: Good to know I can use bitset, but in my problem the number of elements are thousands to hundreds of thousands, and fairly dense.